# simplexml handle quotes into entities

Tags: php

Input strings are:

`<input type="hidden" value="CZĘŚCI"" name="userlogin">`

`<input type="hidden" value="CZĘŚCI'" name="userlogin">`

If I try to handle this with **simplexml_load_string** this return parse error.

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error

I know that this is incorrect html and I should use `htmlspecialchars` or etc functions for sanitaze html but the strings comes to me from an external source and I can't control it. I need to parse html with errors.

How to handle this and get value of this element?

Comment: simplexml_load_string($xmldata, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_NOBLANKS);

Comment: remove second close quote here - `value="CZĘŚCI""` and add root item - https://eval.in/598358

Comment: Manish Jesani, it return false; splash58 - I can't do this, because input string may be different html.

Comment: Is that seconf quote typo or in source string?

Comment: splash58, Yes. I have string that come to me from external source (API) and I need to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleXml can only parse valid XML. You are trying to parse invalid HTML.

You can use DOM to achieve what you want:

```
$string = <<< HTML
<input type="hidden" value="CZĘŚCI'" name="userlogin">
HTML;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' . $string);
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('input')->item(0)->getAttribute("value");
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
```